# Chrome extension - GCM - Image not loading

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-cloud-messaging

if I put my iconUrl as the following, it works:

```
iconUrl: 'assets/img/cat.jpg/',
```

However, if I put is as the following, it doesn't

```
iconUrl: 'assets/img/'+ message.data.imgUrl+'/',
```

I debugged to find the correct value present in message.data.imgUrl (cat.jpg). What am I doing incorrect?

Comment: How about try to set it in a string while concatenating it? `var _icon = 'assets/img/'+message.data.imgUrl+'/'` and then set it on the `iconUrl` property.

Comment: The trailing slash doesn't look right

Comment: It was because of permissions. If I hard code the value in its okay but if its dynamic, it somehow needs permission in manifest.